# TRUE checkboxes / total amount of checkboxes - Google spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help.

See the spreadsheet below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GwA_2DpyZBmDwaRvcln89DN5TjIvtibO_aB2gY769F0/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D11; TRUE)&"/"&COUNTA(D2:D11)&" boxes checked"
```